# MySQL table inside table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering what is the right way to store the following data inside an MySQL DB.

Let's say an object for example a video. and I want to store the the rating which was give to it by other user, so on option is create a column and store the ID of the users and their rating in a complex way, like that:

```
| ID | video_name | rating (usrID,rating)    |
| 5  | cool video | (158,4),(5875,1),(585,5) |
```

I guess that it is not the most efficient way to do so.
Is there a way to store a table inside of a row? what is the most efficient way to do it so I can use SQL query on the rating without processing the data via a PHP code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a second table, `ratings`:

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| video_id | user_id | rating |
+----------+---------+--------+
|        5 |     158 |      4 |
|        5 |    5875 |      1 |
|        5 |     585 |      5 |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

You can then *group* and/or [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) this table in queries, as desired; for example:

```
SELECT   videos.*, AVG(ratings.rating)
FROM     videos JOIN ratings ON videos.id = ratings.video_id
GROUP BY videos.id
```

Answer (score 6):

Normalize it

Have 2 tables.

I.e.

```
ID   Video_name
5    Cool Video
```

The second being

```
vid_id    userid   rating
5         158      4
5         5875     1
5         585      5
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal way is an entity relationship diagram.

Then you have

ratings * --- 1 video

That is, you have a table "video"

```
ID | Name
5  | cool video
```

And a table "ratings"

```
ID | value | USERID | video_ID
1  |  4    | 158    |  5
2  |  1    |  5875  |  5
3  |  5    |  585   |  5
```